# "Resource busy" error when using `dd` to copy disk img to SD card

Tags: sd-card, operating-systems, macos

I've downloaded Raspbian wheezy from the [Raspberry Pi downloads](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) page and following the [RPi Easy SD Card Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup) wiki page.

I formatted the SD card, and `cd`ed into the folder containing the Raspbian img file, but when I run `sudo dd if=2013-07-26-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/disk2s1 bs=1m`, this is the output I get:

```
dd: /dev/disk2s1: Resource busy
```

I tried it again with `/dev/disk2` as the output file, but get the same error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong/why the img isn't being copied over.

This is the (relevant) output of `$ diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *32.5 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 YQFORKLIFT              32.5 GB    disk2s1
```

As well as `$ df -h`:

```
ysim:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
...
/dev/disk2s1    30Gi  1.7Mi   30Gi     1%    /Volumes/YQFORKLIFT
```

And this is what I see under **System Profiler** -> **Card Reader**:

```
Built in SD Card Reader:

  Vendor ID:    0x05ac
  Product ID:   0x8403
  Revision: 1.00
  Serial Number:    000000009833

SDHC Card:

  Capacity: 32.48 GB (32,479,641,600 bytes)
  Removable Media:  Yes
  BSD Name: disk2
  Partition Map Type:   MBR (Master Boot Record)
  S.M.A.R.T. status:    Not Supported
  Volumes:
YQFORKLIFT:
  Available:    32.47 GB (32,465,321,984 bytes)
  Capacity: 32.48 GB (32,475,447,296 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  File System:  MS-DOS FAT32
  BSD Name: disk2s1
  Mount Point:  /Volumes/YQFORKLIFT
```

Comment: this should be tagged with OSX or similar

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found my answer in the [very next section of the wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_command_line_tools_.282.29); silly me. I found that the solution didn't go much into detail about what kind or error messages you see though, and thought it might be helpful to have the exact error message "googleable". I also found the instructions slightly unclear (especially around step 8/9; I wasn't sure if the partition had to be left unmounted), so I tried to rephrase some of it:

[this assumes that your SD card has been formatted already]

1. Run `df -h` to locate the SD card's partition, which will be in the pattern `/dev/diskns1`, where `n` is an integer. In this case, it's `/dev/disk2s1` (the other two are external USB hard drives). And yeah, I know I gave it a weird name...

   ```
    $ df -h
    Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
    /dev/disk0s2   233Gi  125Gi  108Gi    54%    /
    devfs          114Ki  114Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
    map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /net
    map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /home
    /dev/disk1s1   466Gi  351Gi  115Gi    76%    /Volumes/Elements
    /dev/disk3s1   466Gi  276Gi  189Gi    60%    /Volumes/Elements 1
    /dev/disk2s1    30Gi  1.7Mi   30Gi     1%    /Volumes/YQFORKLIFT
   ```
2. Unmount the partition:

   ```
    $ sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk2s1
    Volume YQFORKLIFT on disk2s1 unmounted
   ```
3. Check that it's been unmounted/it no longer shows up when you run `df -h` (otherwise that's what causes the `Resource busy` error above - see [here](http://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/getting-started-raspberry-pi-install-raspbian/)).

   ```
    $ df -h
    Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
    /dev/disk0s2   233Gi  125Gi  108Gi    54%    /
    devfs          114Ki  114Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
    map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /net
    map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /home
    /dev/disk1s1   466Gi  351Gi  115Gi    76%    /Volumes/Elements
    /dev/disk3s1   466Gi  276Gi  189Gi    60%    /Volumes/Elements 1
   ```
4. *While it's still unmounted*, run `sudo dd bs=1m if=/path/to/extracted/raspberry-pi-img.img of=/dev/rdiskn`, replacing `n` with the `N` in `/dev/diskNs1` from step 1. Make sure to write to `/dev/rdiskN` (the disk) and **NOT** `/dev/diskNs1` (the partition), which is something else that causes the `Resource busy` error.

   ```
    $ sudo dd bs=1m if=2013-07-26-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/rdisk2
    1850+0 records in
    1850+0 records out
    1939865600 bytes transferred in 151.663501 secs (12790590 bytes/sec)
   ```
5. The SD card is now re-mounted and named `boot`!

   ```
    $ df -h
    Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
    /dev/disk0s2   233Gi  125Gi  108Gi    54%    /
    devfs          115Ki  115Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
    map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /net
    map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /home
    /dev/disk1s1   466Gi  351Gi  115Gi    76%    /Volumes/Elements
    /dev/disk3s1   466Gi  276Gi  189Gi    60%    /Volumes/Elements 1
    /dev/disk2s1    56Mi   18Mi   37Mi    34%    /Volumes/boot
   ```

Comment: Super helpful thanks. I had to use `sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` instead (which is in fact the only step I needed to take to re-run the dd command)

Comment: I just unmounted the volume and then used the ddrescue / dd directly on the disk, and it worked just fine. I don't think the other steps, are really necessary.

Comment: Could you explain why it says `/dev/rdisk2` instead of `/dev/disk2`? Where does the `r` come from?

Comment: @oschlueter it is way faster to use the raw disks. See https://superuser.com/a/631601

Comment: This was really helpful thank you!